# Why don't we pass any argument a function defined in 'views.py' - Django

Tags: django

In a Django project, when we define a function in `viwes.py`, it's expecting a one argument (something called `request` argument).

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_homepage_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>This is the homepage")
```

But in `url.py`, when we pass `my_homepage_view` in to `url()`function,  we don't pass any argument to `my_homepage_view()` function. In this case, I didn't pass any argument to my_homepage_view(). But it worked fine.

**url.py**

```
from lern_django.views import my_homepage_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', my_homepage_view)
]
```

Please can you explain me how was that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple word, when you request a page in your application, django itself creates
HttpRequest object and binds it to the responsible views as a first argument.

Go to the settings.py file and find following:

`ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'`

When you request a page in django application following happens:

1) Django will look at your settings.py file and find ROOT_URLCONF and determines, which urls to follow

2) Every HTTPRequest from your browser will have URLCONF attribute associate with it.

3) Based on this URLCONF value in your HTTPRequest from browser, django map it to the ROOT_URLCONF

4) Django then look for urlpatterns in your urls and iterate over all the urls and exist on first occurence of given url pattern.

5) And, based on url mapping, given view will be loaded. The view will be called with HTTPRequest as a first parameter.

Comment: Sorry, but still I can't understand it. Could you please explain it me a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

The `url` method you're using here is configuring the Django application to use that view function for that url.  When Django processes a request, it will parse the HTTP request into a [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/) object and pass that to your view function.